# Merge multiple two-dimensional arrays into one two-dimesional array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, ecmascript-6, array-merge

How do you combine these arrays into one merged array?
The data is from a table with rows and columns.

One array contains data of an entire single column.

I would like to merge these columns into one array with 3 columns.

```
//array from col 1
let firstArray = [
    [100],      //row 1, col 1
    [200],      //row 2, col 1
    [300]       //row 3, col 1
]

//array from col 2
let secondArray = let firstArray = [
    ['a'],      //row 1, col 2
    ['b'],      //row 2, col 2
    ['c']       //row 3, col 2
]

//array from col 2
let secondArray = let firstArray = [
    ['run'],        //row 1, col 3
    ['hide'],       //row 2, col 3
    ['seek']        //row 3, col 3
]
```

Expected merged array output:

```
let mergedArray = [
    [100, 'a', 'run'],      //row 1, col 123
    [200, 'b', 'hide'],     //row 2, col 123
    [300, 'b', 'seek']      //row 3, col 123
]
```

Comment: Just an afterthought on reading your question, you are combining an arrays into combined arrays because they are data. Are you perhaps not searching to create a data model instead? As in  a collection of objects with named properties instead of a collection of arrays?
It would be easy enough to modify the accepted answer by altering the return line into for example `return {id:item1[0], char:item2[0],descr: item3[0]};`

Comment: The data range above is from a Google sheet table that's why it looks like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const firstArray = [
    [100],      //row 1, col 1
    [200],      //row 2, col 1
    [300]       //row 3, col 1
];
const secondArray = [
    ['a'],      //row 1, col 2
    ['b'],      //row 2, col 2
    ['c']       //row 3, col 2
];
const thirdArray = [
    ['run'],        //row 1, col 3
    ['hide'],       //row 2, col 3
    ['seek']        //row 3, col 3
];

const mergedArray = firstArray.map((item1, i) => {
  const item2 = secondArray[i];
  const item3 = thirdArray[i];
  return [item1[0], item2[0], item3[0]];
});
console.log(mergedArray);
```